# Unable to start Rails Server with Amazon Route 53 DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have been trying hard to up my Rails Server which is deployed in Amazon EC2 and access it using Route 53.

I have create a simple record sets for `students.aalizwel.com` in Route 53 console and also
mapped my Registrar name servers with Amazon's nameservers.

Following is the screenshot.
[image]

I have my Rails server running in Amazon EC2 with elastic IP as mentioned above
in record set `students.aalizwel.com`.

I have started the server as usual :

```
~/aalizwel$ rails s
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
....
```

Following are issues I am facing:

- Unable to ping `aalizwel.com`.
- Able to ping `students.aalizwel.com` but can't able to access rails server through
  url `http://students.aalizwel.com:3000`

Could anybody help me where I might go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to ping aalizwel.com

You can't ping it because there is no A record at that name, only the SOA.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> aalizwel.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41528
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aalizwel.com.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
aalizwel.com.       899 IN  SOA ns-1191.awsdns-20.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 161 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 16 09:02:16 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

> Able to ping students.aalizwel.com but can't able to access rails server through url http://students.aalizwel.com:3000

There is an nginx server running on port 80:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.1
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 07:03:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Aug 2014 11:18:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "53e0bd8b-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

You will likely need to get your Rails app running so it is proxied from the nginx server over to the port 3000 running instance. I am guessing port 3000 is blocked at the firewall, which would be standard default behavior for an EC2 instance unless you change the firewall rules.

Look into running nginx as a reverse proxy with Rails - you should provide articles on your favorite search engine providing guidance.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. It was firewall issue (or security groups issue). I am new to AWS services and ditn't know we need to add TCP rule with 3000 port to anywhere IP (this link helped me http://www.frontcoded.com/rails-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html)